# How to add multiple pages in AIR for Android

Tags: android, iphone, flash, air, adobe

I want to add multiple pages in my Android App, similar to the home screen on my phone, I want to be able to swipe left and right to see multiple pages.

I'm developing my app in Adobe Flash CC 2014 using "AIR 16.0 for Android".

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with different approaches for this problem. You could create some [SwipeGestures](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/) to detect that or you could go the way Flash went since 1999, setup a Movieclip (or many) and listen for onMouseDown (ontouchstart) events and then say mc.[startDrag](http://www.kirupa.com/flash/easy_drag_drop_flash_as3.htm)(); (you want to limit the drag-movement [to the X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433835/as3-how-to-startdrag-only-on-x-axis)). Then onMouseUp (ontouchend) you can determine if the current MC is relativly cented and then tween it into the middle of the screen, or if the page is to far left/right and therefore page to the next page. There is also a Touch Drag implementation out of the box with [ontouchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009821/how-to-impliment-a-onmousedown-and-onmouseup-on-a-touch-screen-iphone) .

Basicly what you are looking for is some kind of [coverflow for AS3](https://www.google.de/search?q=coverflow+as3&oq=coverflow+as3&aqs=chrome..69i57.1791j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) ... or something a lot less fancy. Please make yourself comfortable with startDrag and StopDrag and you will see how you get there my doing.